# OpenCV Visual Studio Video I/O doesnt work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, video, opencv

Intro:

Hi, I'm having problems whenever I try to retrieve some video input either from
a file or from the camera.

I'm following the tutorials that are given in the book: "Learning OpenCV computer vision with the
openCV library".I can'd get the examples which you use either camera input or video file input to work. These examples are 2-2 and 2-9.

---

Code:

- The code im using for the example 2-2 (video input) is:

  ```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "highgui.h"
  #include <cv.h>


  int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "C:\\Users\\$catia video tutorial 3.avi" );
  IplImage* frame;

  while(1) {
      frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
      if( !frame ) break;
      cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
      char c = cvWaitKey(33);
      if( c == 27 ) break;
  }
  cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
  cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
  }
  ```
- The code im using for the example 2-9 (camera input) is:

  ```
     #include "stdafx.h"
     #include <highgui.h>
     #include <cv.h>


      int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
      CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);
      IplImage* frame;

  while(1) {
      frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
      //if( !frame ) break;
      cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
      char c = cvWaitKey(33);
  if( c == 27 ) break;
  }
  cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
  cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
  return 0;
  }
  ```

---

Conditions:

The reason I'm asking help for both examples at the same time is  because i think the problem is the same for both! Both of them are short examples.

- I'm using OpenCV 2.2 on  a Windows 7 x64 machine with Visual Studio 2010
- I've added all the Opencv libraries and include files correctly in my project properties.
- My camera does work properly with other programs.
- Image input works fine. It's the videos that don't.

---

Output:

- The example 2-2 gives me an "Access Violation exception" as soon as it calls the "cvCreateFileCapture" function.
- Example 2-9 displays a pop up window which asks me to select a video device. I obviously select the only choice which is the bisonCam that comes with my laptop. Then it opens an empty window and does nothing.
- In example 2-9 the camera led turns on.

---

So...:

If anyone has an idea of what I'm missing I'd thank your advice  a lot!!  :D

Comment: Hi,

I think in your first example , the problem is your Path. The path contains spaces "catia video tutorial 3.avi". Please try renaming it as "catia_video_tutorial_3.avi"

Comment: Also you may refer this very small but very usefull tutorial for your help, 
    http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/

Comment: Have you built OpenCV yourself or you are using the binaries?

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your file without a dollar sign ($).  That could be causing the problem with example 2-2 (the code itself looks good).

Comment: Misha && skg--Thanks.I've changed the path to "c://catia.avi". Still calls the same error though. Bob-- I havent built any binaries, though i dont know if they're necessary for Visual Studio 2010. I'll read more about it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with double forward slashes?

Comment: Thats the convention for directing files with openCV. Dont know if thats how it works in general.